# Java Spring Audio chat

Tags: java, audio, webrtc, java-websocket, tyrus

How can I develop web application that allow audio chat to users, using Java and Spring?
I have used WebSocket within Java Web 7 ([https://tyrus.java.net/][Project Tyrus]), and it works great with text massages.

But for audio chat I can't figure it out.
I tried to use WebRTC to detect microphone, here is the client side code:

```
     var ws2 = "ws://localhost:8080/WindTest/voiceChat/asd/username";
 var websocket = new WebSocket(ws2);

 var session = {
 audio: true,
 video: false
  };
  function initializeRecorder(stream) {
  var audioContext = window.AudioContext;
  var context = new audioContext();
  var audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  var bufferSize = 2048;
 // create a javascript node
 //var recorder = context.createJavaScriptNode(bufferSize, 1, 1);
 var recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
 // specify the processing function
 recorder.onaudioprocess = sendAudio;
 // connect stream to our recorder
 audioInput.connect(recorder);
 // connect our recorder to the previous destination
 recorder.connect(context.destination);
 }

 function onError(error){
 console.log(error);
 }
 navigator.getUserMedia(session, initializeRecorder, onError);

 function sendAudio(e) {
 var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
 //Send audio over websocket
 websocket.send(msg);
 }
```

Server side:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/voiceChat/{room}/{username}")
public class VoiceChatEndPoint {

    @OnMessage
    public void broadcastMsg(Object object, Session session) {
        boolean roomExist = false;
        for (Session peer : session.getOpenSessions()) {
            try {
                peer.getBasicRemote().sendObject(object);
                //                    roomExist = true;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(VoiceChatEndPoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (EncodeException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(VoiceChatEndPoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have got an exception, I think it's about decoding and encoding, but I'm not sure how to handle it:

```
Info:   Unhandled exception in endpoint com.wind.ptt.VoiceChatEndPoint.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Text message handler not found.       Session: 'TyrusSession{uri=/WindTest/voiceChat/asd/username, id='6899d950-9e2e-4950-8bb8-03bd839253c0',   endpointWrapper=TyrusEndpointWrapper{endpointClass=null, endpoint=org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint@5bb273b4, contextPath='/WindTest'}}'.
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusEndpointWrapper.onMessage(TyrusEndpointWrapper.java:752)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocket.onMessage(TyrusWebSocket.java:200)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.frame.TextFrame.respond(TextFrame.java:135)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ProtocolHandler.process(ProtocolHandler.java:622)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocketEngine$TyrusReadHandler.handle(TyrusWebSocketEngine.java:394)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusHttpUpgradeHandler.onDataAvailable(TyrusHttpUpgradeHandler.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.processDataAvailable(InputBuffer.java:488)
```

How can I make audio chatting with Java(Tyrus project, websocket, Spring)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Tyrus APIs accept either a String or a binary format input. My understanding from the exception you posted is that you are passing the audio as a text, somehow. 
The exception is from this method: 

`public void onMessage(TextFrame frame)
        // line no: 200 of TyrusWebSocket 
      this.endpointWrapper.onMessage(this, frame.getTextPayload());
      .....
  }`

Comment: Try  `sendBinary(ByteBuffer data)` instead of `sendObject(..)` in `peer.getBasicRemote().sendObject(object);`

Comment: Thanks guys,
I used the following code and runs fine:
    peer.getBasicRemote().sendBinary((ByteBuffer) object);
But I'm facing another problem now, in the client, I'm getting BLOB variable that should be on speaker to let the client hear it.
Do you think should post the problem here in the comments or create a new question?

Comment: Please create a new question if it is not answered in Stack Overflow yet and provide the link to the question here.